# Битрикс компонент включаемой области не работает

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает компонент включаемой области в news.list - не появляется кнопочка на странице и поэтому не получается редактировать эту область?

```
    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:main.include",
    "",
    Array(
        "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
        "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc",
        "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "PATH" => "/include/cars.php"
    )
);?>
```

Хотя , если этот код перенести в index.php или в другой файл, который находится в корне, то он работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
<? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:main.include",
"",
Array(
    "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
    "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc",
    "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "",
    "PATH" => SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/include/cars.php"
));?>
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло(

Comment: А где находится директория /include/ ?

Comment: в корне проекта

Comment: Тогда SITE_TENPLATE_PATH конечно не подойдёт) Думаю все понимают, что это константа содержит путь до папки текущего шаблона) Ответ напишу ниже.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:main.include",
    "",
    Array(
        "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
        "PATH" => SITE_DIR."include/somefile.php",
        "AREA_FILE_RECURSIVE" => "N",
        "EDIT_MODE" => "html",
    ),
    false,
);?>
```